# Uso de la clase IntentIntegrator de Zxing en la versión 3.4.0

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Tengo una actividad que extiende de la clase fragment y Uso varios Intents para otras actividades en este fragment

Con estos dos accedo a los contactos del teléfono

```
btncontact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,1);
            }
        })
btncontactpide.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,2);

            }
        });
```

Y en este uso la clase IntentIntegrator de zxing-android-embedded en la versión 3.4.0 pero esta versión no me deja pasarle el requestcode de la actividad por lo que tengo problemas al identificar el resultado de cada actividad en el método onActivityResult

```
public void scanFromFragment() {
IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this)
    .setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES)
    .setPrompt("Escaneo el código QR del cupón")
    .setCaptureActivity(Captura.class)
    .initiateScan();
}
```

Así es como tengo el método onActivityResult pero no devuelve el resultado de todas las actividades

```
   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Escaneo cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if(result.getContents().length() != 16){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Código QR invalido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            String strcupon = result.getContents();
            try{
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:"+ (("*662*" + strcupon)+Uri.encode("#")))));

            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        Uri uri =data.getData();
        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,null);
        
if (resultCode !=0 && requestCode == 1){
    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        int inNumero = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        String numero = cursor.getString(inNumero);
        String cont=numero.substring(3,11);
        txtnumero.setText(cont);
    }
}else if(resultCode !=0 && requestCode ==2){
    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        int inNumero = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        String numero = cursor.getString(inNumero);
        String cont=numero.substring(3,11);
        txtnumpedir.setText(cont);
    }
}

        }  
}
```

¿Alguien que me ayude a como pasar el requestcode de la actividad con el intentintegrator para esa versión de zxing-android-embedded 3.4.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema por el cual es que en la `Activity` que se abre, al cerrarla debes hacer uso de :

> [setResult(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setResult(int)) Establece el resultado de que su actividad volverá
> a la persona que llamó.
>
> Parámetros `resultCode` int: el código de resultado que se propaga de
> nuevo a la actividad de origen, a menudo `RESULT_CANCELED` o `RESULT_OK`

Por ejemplo para cerrar la Activity que mandaste llamar usas setResult(RESULT_OK) y al regresar a la Activity inicial se llamará `onActivityResult()` con el valor de `resquestCode`.

```
private void SaveContactsFinish() { 

    guardaContactos();
 
    setResult(RESULT_OK); 
 
    finish(); //Termina activity 
  }
```